# How does Android check Internet connection?

Tags: android

I'm interested in how Android checks internet connectivity. For example in our company's wifi the wlan-symbol turns grey, even if there is working connection for http/https/dns etc.
At Home (No restrictions on Firewall) it turns blue.

Which checks are done in background? Does anybody know it in detail?

Comment: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530846/how-to-programmatically-check-availibilty-of-internet-connection-in-android> <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326767/how-do-you-check-the-internet-connection-in-android>

Comment: First Search!Check here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783117/network-listener-android

Comment: Guys my question was no code matter. It was a technical question, which is done by android to determine an connection as up or down

Comment: that question is probably more suitable to http://android.stackexchange.com/ then here. SO is for programming questions. Anyway, to be absolutely sure you can check the source code, it's there. But if I had to guess I would say that they ping some google server to test connection.

Answer (score 0):

```
public final boolean isInternetOn() {

    ConnectivityManager connec =  (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if ( connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
            connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING ||
            connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING ||
            connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ) 
    {
        return true;
    } else if ( connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED ||  
            connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED  ) 
    {

        return false;
    }
    return false;
}//end of the Internet Connection Checking
```

Comment: This is what i found on related posts, too. But what is Android doing exactly? DNS resolve or any HTTP request?

Comment: send mail to Android and Ask Direct to android os Team

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
   ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
     NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
  if (ni == null) {
  // There are no active networks.
```

return false;
     } else
   return true;
     }

```
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: This is what i found on related posts, too.
But what is Android doing exactly? DNS resolve or any HTTP request?

Comment: what is android doing to determine if the connection is up or down?
In this case, not by code.

Comment: try this
 NetworkInfo i = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
  if (i == null)
    return false;
  if (!i.isConnected())
    return false;
  if (!i.isAvailable())
    return false;
  return true;

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function to check network in your app:

```
  public boolean isConnectToInternet() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) 
        getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity != null) {
          NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
          if (info != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
              if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                return true;
              }
        }
        return false;
      }
```

and you must add this permission at manifest.xml:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```