# how to detect internet connection in android studio

Tags: android, connect, connectivity, networkinfo

I have following code to detect if there is internet connection available or not. But if I have no internet connection only the data connection is "ON" it still works. what I should do?

```
   ConnectivityManager cManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(this.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);


    NetworkInfo ninfo = cManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();


    if(ninfo!=null && ninfo.isConnected())

    {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    else
    {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Not Available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: Do you have `INTERNET` and `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permission in manifest?

Comment: You would actually have to make a network call to see if the internet connection is available.

Comment: Check which connection Android is recognizing: `Toast.makeText(this, "Available: " + ninfo.getTypeName(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatically check availibilty of internet connection in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530846/how-to-programmatically-check-availibilty-of-internet-connection-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

Use this `NetworkUtils` class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class NetworkUtils {

  private static int TYPE_WIFI = 1;
  private static int TYPE_MOBILE = 2;
  private static int TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED = 0;

  public static int getConnectivityStatus(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (networkInfo != null) {
      if (networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI
          && networkInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {

        return TYPE_WIFI;

      } else if (networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE
          && networkInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
        return TYPE_MOBILE;
      }
    }
    return TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED;
  }

  public static boolean isNetworkConnected(Context context) {
    int networkStatus = getConnectivityStatus(context);
    if (networkStatus == TYPE_WIFI || networkStatus == TYPE_MOBILE) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Use like this:

```
if(NetworkUtils.isNetworkConnected(this)){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

use the `ConnectivityManager` class.
here is the java class:

```
 ConnectivityManager manager =(ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
 NetworkInfo activeNetwork = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (null != activeNetwork) {
            if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI){
                //we have WIFI
            }
            if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE){
                //we have cellular data
            }
        } else{
            //we have no connection :(
        }
```

do not forget to ask for the permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```