# Mobile network check

Tags: android

I am working on an application that has OTP screen integrated with it. There is one minor issue there. I have to check for two conditions, one is, if the network is not available then I have to display an error message that `Network not available`. Else if user has entered a wrong OTP then then error message should say that 'Wrong OTP entered'.

Right now I am displaying a common message for both cases. No if else. I want to separate them into two. My problem is how do we check for Mobile network issue, if its available or not?

```js
if (task.isSuccessful()) {
  if (previousScreenTitle == R.string.login) {
    userPrivateInfo = Constants.ALL_USERS_REFERENCE.child(userMobileNumber);
    userPrivateInfo.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        /* Check if User mobile number is found in database */
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
          startActivity(new Intent(OTP.this, NammaApartmentsHome.class));
        }
        /* User record was not found in firebase hence we navigate them to Sign Up page*/
        else {
          Intent intent = new Intent(OTP.this, SignUp.class);
          intent.putExtra(Constants.MOBILE_NUMBER, userMobileNumber);
          startActivity(intent);
        }
        finish();
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

      }
    });
  } else {
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, new Intent());
    finish();
  }
} else {
  textResendOTPOrVerificationMessage.setText(R.string.check_network_connection);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check internet access on Android? InetAddress never times out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-times-out)

Comment: Also you might like [Check Network and Internet Connection - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31283443/3166697) or [Check for Active internet connection Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17717749/3166697) or [How to programmatically check availibilty of internet connection in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4530846/3166697)

Answer (score -1):

Use this method

```
private boolean chechInternetConnection() {
    connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivityManager != null) {
        if (connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
                connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
            connected = true;
            Log.i("Internet", "Connected");
        } else {
            connected = false;
            Log.i("Internet", "Not Connected");
        }
    }
    return connected;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The following snippet shows how to use the [ConnectivityManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager) to query the active network and determine if it has Internet connectivity.

```
ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                      activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
```

**Determine the type of your internet connection**

Device connectivity can be provided by mobile data, WiMAX, Wi-Fi, and ethernet connections. By querying the type of the active network, as shown below, you can alter your refresh rate based on the bandwidth available.

```
boolean isWiFi = activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;
```

[Check Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring) for detailed understanding.

Hope this helps.